Trivial question: is the [instantiation] tag separate from the [algorithm-design] tag?
For a new question I asked, I wanted to tag it instantiation. However, upon discovering such tag doesn't exist, I turned to algorithm-design.
I'd think algorithm-design encompasses instantiation, for the obvious reason that instantiation (or leaving the parameters for it) is part of designing an algorithm.
What do you think? Do we need to go further aliasing instantiation with algorithm-design?
